# How to define an impicit conversion from one to another existing type in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, casting, implicit, enrich-my-library

Let's say we've got a `Foo` class in a library we use and want (in a code file of ours) `Foo` instances to be implicitly cast to `String` instances whenever a `Foo` instance is met in a place a `String` instance is required. How to achieve this in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
implicit def stringFromFoo(foo: Foo): String = foo.toString
```

Comment: And don't forget you'll need to import this method or place it somewhere compiler will find it (in superclass or a trait of your class, package object, etc.).